# RDLC expressions and datasets

Tags: .net, reporting-services, expression, rdlc

I am quite a beginner developer so I apologize if my question sounds a bit broad. I am creating an RDLC report, but i'm not sure how to get fields/items to link in my datasets.

For example, I want to add an expression to a textbox, and then add a value to it, but the data that I'm looking for from a specific dataset isn't available for that specific RDLC

I know that you have to create a new dataset with models to get the actual fields, and connect it to your database table. Is there a specific procedure to follow or does it vary from company to company?

Comment: Are you retrieving the data from a MS SQL database, and what does the query look like?
What does the data look like and what expression do you want to add?
Can the expression be used in the SQL query?

These question will help us, help you.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me Jon! I apologize if I can't even understand what you mean by your question though. But yes we are using an MS SQL database. From what I can tell, is that the company uses an RDLC file to display the report,  a c# file in which the dataset lies


  `public string Generate(Guid id, string tokens, CommunicationIdentifierTypes identifierType, Guid templateId)
        {
            var token = DatasetFactory.FromXmlString(tokens);
            var models = new List<ClaimModel>();`

Comment: not sure about your situation. It might be worth adding a C# tag into your post and see if there's anyone else out there...

Comment: A good starting point is http://gotreportviewer.com/: it really helps me when I learned RDLC. In particular give a look here: http://gotreportviewer.com/definedata and http://gotreportviewer.com/objectdatasources.